# Building a web app for time effectiveness: Rails, Django, Node or alternative

Tags: java, javascript, ruby-on-rails, django, node.js

I've started learning Rails, Django, and Node.js. and I've found that learning to use these frameworks takes an enormous amount of time.

Because Rails and Django have so many parts the complexity makes it hard to remember how to do everything. Node.js is simpler, but I have found that you have to spend a lot of time making things that are already available configured in rails and django.

In terms of time effectiveness how do these three options size up? I've spent enough time on each to get a basic understanding, but would like to know which option (or an alternative) makes the most sense to purse investing a lot of time learning. And in terms of payoff, which will enable me to accomplish the most?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this question isn't really a good fit for stack overflow. Stack overflow works best for specific technical questions (eg "I ran code X and it's giving me error Y"). A question like this is likely to spur opinionated answers - which we have discovered often leads to flame wars... and that is detrimental to our community. So Stack Overflow decided not to allow opinionated questions. If you have a specific, technical question, feel free to update your question to ask that instead, otherwise your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Taryn! I thought that my question was specific since I'm asking in terms of time effectiveness, but I can see what you mean. I would like to keep the question open as I'm am finding the answers very helpful. Any ideas on how to improve the wording to better focus on the time effectivenss of these tools?

Comment: Opinion-based questions can often be interesting, and their answers useful... even though they fit the "primarily opinion based" criteria for closing ;) I don't think I could see a way to reword it to fit, without entirely changing the question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's completely depend on you, But in my opinion, You should not compare Rails and Django with Node.js. It's better to compare Node.js with Ruby or Python and compare Rails and Django with Node.js based full stack frameworks like [Geddy](http://geddyjs.org/), [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!) or [Total.js](http://www.totaljs.com/).

I have about 3-4 years experience of working with these frameworks and I can simply say that while Django and Rails speed up your development process, Node.js based frameworks are more flexible and most of the time give you better performance, But I It's better for you to learn the real procedure of web development instead of sticking to an specific framework. When you learn how to develop the web, You can easily switch between frameworks and In real world you can't say that one framework is better than another one, You should choose your framework based on the project needs.

The bottom line:
You can read these nice articles and comparisons:

[Why we moved from NodeJS to Ruby on Rails](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3971867)

[Which should I learn?](http://www.quora.com/Ruby-vs-Python/Which-should-I-learn-Django-or-Rails)

[Python vs Django](http://maxivak.com/python-django-vs-ruby-on-rails/)

[Ruby on Rails vs. Node.js at LinkedIn - InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/10/Ruby-on-Rails-Node-js-LinkedIn)

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback Alireza! What exactly do you mean by "real procedure of web development"? Would this be learning first with Node.js or php as opposed to using a framework like Rails or Django?

Comment: Yes, It's better to learn about HTTP, MVC structures, RESTAPI design, Databases, Caching and more, then you can code in different frameworks simply by learning their syntax. Starting with Node.js can be a nice idea, But as Node.js flow control is little confusing, I prefer to starting with ruby. And I really advice you to don't start with PHP, It's simple and easy but hide most of the backend flow from your sight. (Sorry for my weak English)

Comment: Gotcha, so if I were to start with Ruby (just to clarify this is Ruby and not Rails?), do you know of any good places to start. I tried googling for web design with ruby (not rails) and couldn't come up with much

Comment: @alexbhandari [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/learn) is a good point to start, And [this article](https://medium.com/how-i-learned-ruby-rails/how-i-trained-to-learn-rails-e08c94e2a51e) can help you a lot.